# how to pass data from one function to another function angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am filtering data while searching in my application. I am facing the issue to write if condition to check the function selected data and second function filter data.

- I have 5 side menus in my application. If I click any one of that, I need to store that value in a variable.
- I have another function, I am looping the results there.But I need to check already stored value, and the current function's response value is same or not.

```js
$scope.toggleTab = function (id) {
      $scope.categoryId = id;
}
```

And my another function is,

```js
$scope.getTags = function () {
    var keywords_regex = new RegExp($scope.search.split(' ').map(function (i) { return '(?=.*' + i + ')'; }).join(''), 'i');
      return $scope.getData.filter(function (data) {
        return !!data.match(keywords_regex);
      }).map(function (data) {
          return data;    
      });
    }
```

In this map function I need to check the result like this,

```js
      }).map(function (data) {
         if( selectedData == data.id){
         return data;
         }

      });
```

How can I do this, I used $rootScope. But When it came inside loop, the result has changed..

Comment: is selectedData undefined on your last map? if so try switching to arrow-functions

Comment: May I know how?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic sorry I don't know arrow functions. How can I achieve this in the above code? can you please modify my code

Comment: change `.map(function (data) {` to `.map(data => {`

Comment: Arrow-functions are useful when you nee to access variables from your outer scope. You should learn these as they are essential:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc